# Uploading images in cross-platform application

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am creating a cross-platform web application that needs to upload images from each device or platform. I successfully used codeigniter file upload that works perfectly but it does not seem to work well on other devices. I have also used cordova but the does not work on mac and windows system. This image path needs to be uploaded to a database and I am using codeigniter as well as Jquery mobile for the responsiveness. Is there any suggestion on the best practice or methods used to upload images in a cross platform application